# How to create if-then-else statement in an oracle sql script?

Tags: oracle, prompt, sql-scripts

I am writing an sql script, whitch should ask a question, and the continuing would depend on the user's input.

I have tried this:

```
prompt script started
accept partitioning prompt "Do you want to partition the table? (Y/N):"
if ($partitioning=Y)
    prompt ok, it will be partitioned
else
    prompt ok, it won't be partitioned
end;
```

But I get

> ORA-00900 exception, the **if** statement is not allowed here.

Is there a way to use if-then-else in a single sql script? Please give me an example, if it possible.

Comment: Which SQL client are you using?

Comment: oracle, I edited the question, sorry

Comment: I think you are confusing sqlplus with SQL.  Bu you can try this - http://www.itbh.at/simulating-control-flow-statements-in-sqlplus/?lang=en

Comment: Oracle is the *DBMS*, not the SQL client.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the comments, I got the answer:

http://www.itbh.at/simulating-control-flow-statements-in-sqlplus/?lang=en

Comment: The link is broken